# Collision Not Working With JavaScript (Screenshot & Collision Function Included)

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

I'm having some issues with collision detection;

The function I am using to check if a rectangle intersects another is:

```
function box_col(ax1, ay1, ax2, ay2, bx1, by1, bx2, by2) {
    return !((ax2 < bx1)||(ax1 > bx2)||(ay1 > by2)||(ay2 < by1));
    }
```

For some reason whenever I am on the edge of the fence, I can't move anymore.
I can move back up however if I walk to the top of the fence, but can't move left or right.

The same goes for when I hit the left, right, and bottom sides.
Once I am by the it's edge respectively, I can no longer move along it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzcp8.png - Screenshot

(The red blocks represent collision areas, since I use view variables for drawing into the canvas)

I know for a fact that all the x,y coordinates passed to box_col are correct.

You can see that I am at the top of the fence, but it wont let me move left or right.
Just back up.
Also, when I am on the left side of the fence, I can't move at all period; It wont even let me move right.

I have searched the web quite a bit, and spent hours on this to try and find the correct collision algorithm, but I obviously still don't get it...

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I think your intersection logic is wrong. Shouldn't there be some && statements in there? If two boxes intersect then it means that something is happening on the x axis AND the y axis.

Comment: You've a lack of the logic here. Your function returns `false` whenever any of the limits is reach. Hence the receiver function thinks _all_ further movement should not be executed...

Comment: It has to, because the function calling it uses it that way.

The script that calls box_col is:

https://gist.github.com/dk81584/2dd3be4b4ce3a0962f82

Comment: _all_ is a keyword here, you need to check the direction of the given movement in the receiver function, and allow it, if the direction is in the limits.

Comment: It already does that in the created instance's step event.
Here is how it looks, when checking if it can move:

https://gist.github.com/dk81584/d8341e40b757a5360367

Comment: Hmm... You maybe want to tag the used library too...?

Comment: The libraries aren't the issue though.
All the coordinates passed to box_col are all valid, and it properly orders the rectangle coords returned by rect() by minX, minY, maxX, maxY.

The issue is the box_col function... I don't understand how to make it work.

Comment: Can you save a simplified (non-working) example at [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Here are the two scripts used:

engine.js is loaded first, then game.js is loaded afterwards.

engine.js - https://gist.github.com/dk81584/d0f9c228dbce3cd62b59

game.js - https://gist.github.com/dk81584/3d263dabaf0f14b25de7

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle that loads the scripts, and puts elements exactly how I have it on my site. But, it wont load images because they are hosted on localhost.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rkzhu/